# How to create a dynamic facebook share link for my web page

Tags: javascript, php, sharing

I currently have this code from one of the solutions provided, but it doesn't work

```
<a href="javascript:fbshareCurrentPage()" target="_blank" alt="Share on Facebook">Facebook</a>
```

the script

```
<script language="javascript">
function fbshareCurrentPage()
{window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+escape(window.location.href)+"&t="+document.title, '<?php echo $artData["title"]?>', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
return false; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little wrong here and there. Please see below. NB I would store title into invisible div container as attribute (if it does not contain HTML):

```
<div id="some_title" data-text="<?php echo $artData["title"];?>"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fbshareCurrentPage() {
        var title = $('#some_title').attr('data-text');
        window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+escape(window.location.href)+"&t="+title, title, "menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600");
    }
</script>
```